# Faulty (register)counter in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86-64, counter

In school we are learning assembly at the moment. Now we got the project to do an base 64 encoder.

I was trying around to read in 12bits (or more) from the command line, but ive got a problem.
the first 6 bit are perfect no problem. bl contains what it should. Now on the second pass i get the same result as in the first pass, even if i type 2 different 6bit sequences. I've tried it all.

If i hardcode [InBuf+6] .. it uses the second 6 bits, so i think I've got a problem with the counter, but I didn't find it yet.

Example:

Input -> 110000110001 (0 and 1 in ascii)

first run -> bl contains 110000 (0 ascii) -> outputs 0

second run -> bl contains 110000 (0 ascii), but actually should contain 110001 (1 ascii) -> outputs 0.

```
_process:
; read byte
xor rax, rax
xor rbx, rbx

mov al, byte [InBuf+r12]
inc r12
and al, 0x01
mov bl, al
shl bl, 1

mov al, byte [InBuf+r12]
inc r12
and al, 0x01
xor bl, al
shl bl, 1

mov al, byte [InBuf+r12]
inc r12
and al, 0x01
xor bl, al
shl bl, 1

mov al, byte [InBuf+r12]
inc r12
and al, 0x01
xor bl, al
shl bl, 1

mov al, byte [InBuf+r12]
inc r12
and al, 0x01
xor bl, al
shl bl, 1

mov al, byte [InBuf+r12]
and al, 0x01
xor bl, al
inc r12

mov al, byte [Base64Table+rbx] 

mov byte [BaseStr+r10], bl

inc r10

call _write

cmp r12, r8
je _exit    

jmp _process
```

Comment: `and al, 0x01` keeps only 1 bit of your input.  Your input is in base-2 ASCII?

Comment: What does your `_write` function do?  Does it zero `r12`?  This code only seems to show the working code, not a [mcve] of your problem.  Also, normally you'd use a loop to convert multiple ASCII digits to an integer.  If you're going to fully unroll the loop iterations, you might as well use `[InBuf+r12+1]` etc.  (Or use SSE2 `pmovmskb`, like in [this code-golf answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/214750/display-the-exponent-from-a-binary-floating-point-number-as-a-decimal-value/214818#214818))

Comment: @PeterCordes
The Input is only bits, so 1 and 0. So I'm only intereted in them, and the input is stored in an string (InBuf).

_write just writes out BaseStr.`_write:
mov rax, 1
mov rdi, 1
mov rsi, BaseStr
mov rdx, BaseStrLen
syscall
ret`. Yea I thought about that (looping), but as im very new to assembly I just wanted to keep it simple, so I could understand what im doing. 

Btw I tried it to with `[InBuf+r12+1]` got the same result, thats why I'm incrementing `r12` it after every step.